# Vue js, импорт плагинов для videojs

Tags: vue.js, videojs

В документации videojs плагины подключаются следующим образом

```
<script src="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/Youtube.min.js"></script>
```

Как я подключаю в vuejs:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <video ref="videoPlayer" class="video-js"></video>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';
    import videojs from 'video.js';
    //import {httpStreaming} from '@videojs/http-streaming'
    import youtube from 'videojs-youtube'

    export default {
        name: "VideoPlayer",
        data() {
            return {
                player: null,
                options: {
                    'youtube': {
                        source: {
                            type: "video/youtube",
                            src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnLV6iwr3sQ'
                        },
                        techOrder: ["youtube"],
                        autoplay: false,
                        controls: true,
                        ytControls: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, function onPlayerReady() {
                console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
            });
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.dispose()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Как правильно подключать плагины?

Answer (score 0):

Этого вполне достаточно:

```
        data() {
            return {
                player: null,
                configs: {}
            }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.configs.youtube = require('videojs-youtube');
        },
```